# How can I create a re-usable CloudFormation template for my Lambda functions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

I have 9 lambda functions as part of a single CloudFormation project.

I feel like the CloudFormation template for each Lambda function is starting to become the same in many places & feels like it's repetitive YAML code.

Is there a way to create a single Lambda configuration & reuse the same code by parameterising input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [CloudFormation Nested Stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html) can help you declare **shared Lambda configuration as a component which you can then use for multiple resources**.

Instead of copying & pasting the same configurations for your Lambda functions, you can create a dedicated child "Lambda" template.

Then, you can point to your Lambda CloudFormation (CF) stack multiple times from one encapsulating CloudFormation template, typically called your "root stack".

[`Parameters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html), [`Outputs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) & [`!GetAtt`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) will be the core tools to help you share data between the child & root stack, as well as parameterising aspects like function name, memory, runtime etc.

---

On an *organisational* scale, [AWS CloudFormation Modules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/modules.html) will be more suitable, which allow you to encapsulate and re-use resource configurations on a larger scale.

[Here's how AWS describes them](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/introducing-aws-cloudformation-modules/):

> Modules are building blocks that can be reused across **multiple CloudFormation templates** and is used just like a native CloudFormation resource.
>
> ...
>
> **This means you can create a module that defines your organization’s standards for a Lambda function and then consume that Lambda module** in another module that defines the patterns for your serverless Amazon API Gateway implementation.

Comment: What about nested sacks? Seems easier in this case.

Comment: @Marcin Very true, I'll add that too to my answer :)

Comment: Ermiya Eskandary discussion the solutions with my team. They suggested Global section is suitable for the use case.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html